# Instance of Container used in Funq

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, funq

I am waching the screencast of Funq but I don't understand something with the following lambda in the testing code :

```
var container = new Container();
container.Register<IBar>(c => new Bar());
```

the declaration :

```
public void Register<TService>(Func<Container, TService> factory) { ... }
```

In the lambda, the **new Bar()** acts as the **TService** and the **c** as the **Container** for the Func used in Register method.

During the execution, when is this c delcared ? Is it the **container** created at the beginning because I do not understand when an instance of a Container is passed to the **Register** method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> During the execution, when is this c declared?

You did, using the following line:

```
var container = new Container();
```

Funq in fact passes an instance to itself to the supplied delegate. This allows you, for instance, to do the following:

```
container.Register<IBar>(c => 
{
    var bar = c.Resolve<Bar>();
    bar.SomeProperty = 5;
    return bar;
});
```

However, passing the container itself to the delegate it quite useless IMO, since this value is always available during registration. For instance, you can also write this:

```
container.Register<IBar>(unused => 
{
    var bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
    bar.SomeProperty = 5;
    return bar;
});
```

In other words, it would have been much easier if the `Register` method accepted a `Func<T>` instead of a `Func<Container, T>`. The previous snippet would have looked like this:

```
container.Register<IBar>(() => 
{
    var bar = container.Resolve<Bar>();
    bar.SomeProperty = 5;
    return bar;
});
```